# Google BigQuery standart SQL insert nested row which has nested rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how to run an INSERT (i guess update?) query to insert into rows which are nested, but latter rows also have a nested schema in themselves.

For instance i have something like
[image]

What would a general template query look like?

I know that for the lines it would look something like 
[image]

Comment: Please try to ask a more specific question, you'll get a more specific answer. Initial state, end results expected?

Comment: Updated with an example schema and what i've gotten so far.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it with:

```
UPDATE test 
SET lines=ARRAY(
SELECT line FROM UNNEST(lines) AS line
UNION ALL
SELECT (
'::someValue::,
ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING,STRING,FLOAT64>>[('someId','someString',1.0)]
)
WHERE id='someId'
```